# Identify if a day of the week is 2nd/3rd etc Mon/Tues/etc day of the month in R

Tags: r, date

Given a date and the day of the week it is, I want to know if there is a code that tells me which of those days of the month it is. For example in the picture below, given 2/12/2020 and "Wednesday" I want to be given the output "2" for it being the second Wednesday of the month.

[image: sample]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that in base R in essentially one operation. You also do not need the second input column.

Here is slower walkthrough:

#### Code

```
dates <- c("2/12/2020","2/11/2020","2/10/2020","2/7/2020","2/6/2020", "2/5/2020")
Dates <- anytime::anydate(dates)   ## one of several parsers
dow   <- weekdays(Dates)           ## for illustration, base R function
cnt   <- (as.integer(format(Dates, "%d")) - 1) %/% 7 + 1

res <- data.frame(dt=Dates, dow=dow, cnt=cnt)
res
```

#### (Final) Output

```
R> res
          dt       dow cnt
1 2020-02-12 Wednesday   2
2 2020-02-11   Tuesday   2
3 2020-02-10    Monday   2
4 2020-02-07    Friday   1
5 2020-02-06  Thursday   1
6 2020-02-05 Wednesday   1
R>
```

Functionality like this is often in dedicated date/time libraries. I wrapped some code from the (C++) Boost date_time library in package RcppBDH -- that allowed to easily find 'the third Wednesday in the last month each quarter' and alike.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!  Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear that, and welcome to StackOverflow!  Feel free to 'accept' the answer (by clicking on the 'tick mark' only you as the asker of the question see) to keep the karma flowing (back to you too).  You can also 'upvote' by clicking on the 'up' triangle.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Comment: No worries.  Hope you'll enjoy StackOverflow.  Answering can be fun too ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
(lubridate::day(your_date) - 1) %/% 7 + 1
```

The idea here is that the first 7 days of the month are all the first for their weekday. Next 7 are 2nd, etc.

```
> (1:30 - 1) %/% 7 + 1
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to offer an alternative calculation for the nth-weekday of the month, you can just divide the day by 7 and always round up:

```
date <- lubridate::mdy("02/12/2020")
ceiling(day(date)/7)
```